# Copy different workbooks from an folder into different sheets in one workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following code to clean the workbook and then to create empty sheets

```
Sub conclusion()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim Path As String, Filename As String



    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" And xWs.Name <> "Summary" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ' create new sheets

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell

    ' copy the workbooks into the sheets (My question )

End Sub
```

and then it should read the path from a cell in my case B2 and look for all xls files in this folder and copy to the crated sheets whose names are in [image: range A2]

I wrote the following

```
 Path= Sheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value ***( it does not read the value of B2, why? )***
  Filename = Dir("Path" & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""

***here is my question, how can I write the following:
COPY THE WORKBOOK 1 INTO SHEET with the name from Cell A2*** 
  Loop
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: Hi Peter, the question is in the code: 1) Path= Sheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value --->  it does not read the value of B2, why?  =>
  Filename = Dir("Path" & "*.xls") can not be read  and 2) COPY THE WORKBOOK 1 INTO SHEET with the name from Cell A2   SEE please the last part of the code

Comment: what do you mean by copying a workbook into a worksheet? Wouldn't it just be the opposite?

Comment: Use the 'Path' value and not a literal string: Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

Comment: @user3598756: I have a folder (C:\My_Work\scortix\) which contains diff. excel files (like file_1.xls, file_2.xls, ....). Now I want go there and copy every workbook  into a sheet  of the existing excel. For instance copy file_1.xls into Total sheet, file_2.xls  into leasing sheet etc.

Comment: What about if 2 workbooks have the same sheet name? How would it copy it here?

Comment: @Sgdva the second workbook is rather empty and has just one sheet where the macro exists and copies all other workbooks as sheets in this workbook

Answer (score 0):

To fix the first problem try:

```
With Application.Workbooks("BookName").Sheets("Summary")
    Path = .Range("B1").Text & "\" & .Range("A2").Text
End With
```

For the second your variable `Path` is in quotes which it shouldn't be as it is not a string but a string variable. Not too sure why you had the wildcard asterisk in there either...

```
Filename = Dir(Path & ".xls")
```

For the last part, your `For Loop` is missing what it is that you want to cycle through (ie. cells)

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
Next MyCell
```

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry for delay the first  problem is fixt within 'with' but I have still problems with 'Dir'  Filename is still empty! In the Loop I want to Import the workbooks from the Path into summary.xls  AS SHEETS! something like (here is: Import the sheets from the Excel file into summary) 
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("summary.xls").Worksheets.count
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("summary.xls").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet